# EmguCV OCR Tesseract different colours and sizes - deep learning in C#

Tags: c#, deep-learning, ocr, tesseract, emgucv

I've found an example about Licence Plate Recognition in C#:

```
http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/License_Plate_Recognition_in_CSharp#License_Plate_Recognition
```

Example with EmguCV and Tesseract.
Example works but in the code I have assign VectorOfVectorOfPoint:

```
CvInvoke.CvtColor(img, gray, ColorConversion.Bgr2Gray);
CvInvoke.Canny(gray, canny, 100, 50, 3, false);
```

But I want to do OCR on text in colour newspaper where there are a lot of images with different coloures and letters with different sizes. I don't know these colours and sizes of fonts and x,y points.
Can I teach OCR to recognize these letters and texts? How to do this dynamically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my past experiences, the given Emgucv Licence Plate Recognition example is outdated and not the greatest. Are you using the default tessdata files from the Tesseract Github repo? There are a variety of different tessdata files for different languages on the repo, and are quite helpful in detecting text in all sorts of fonts and colors. However, if you want to further train your data, try this tutorial here. https://pretius.com/how-to-prepare-training-files-for-tesseract-ocr-and-improve-characters-recognition/